# how to get data about checkbox is checked in javascript file

Tags: knockout.js, checked

how to get data when checkbox is checked.

```
     MyClient =ko.observable(false);
```

this is the select option.

I used

```
   self.MyClient.subscribe(function(newValue){ code goes here...})
```

but it is not what I am looking for, as I click it, it does what I want but again when I unselect same happens because, in both cases value of MyClient is new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Updated] You can make a field required by binding the `required` attribute (`attr` binding) to a boolean. Use the same boolean as is bound to your checkbox. CSS outlines the field in red when it is required in my example.

```js
self = {
  myClient: ko.observable(false),
  myValue: ko.observable(''),
  message: function() {
    console.debug("Valu:", self.myValue());
    if (self.myClient() && !(self.myValue())) {
      return "Please enter value";
    }
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(self);
```

```css
input[required] {
  outline: solid red 2px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: myClient" />
<input data-bind="attr: {required: myClient}, value: myValue" /><span data-bind="text:message()"></span>
```

Comment: Nope I just need js code which will make another field required if MyClient is selected. Is there any way of doing it?

Comment: How can I set validation message for that required field?

Comment: what should I do so  it will not show red border after I fill the required field

Comment: You don't have to use the red border at all. I just did that for my example.
For validation message, you may want to use https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation.

Comment: @Kakos649 I've updated the example once more to add a message that displays when the field is empty. Study it a bit so you understand what is doing what. If you have more questions, ask a new question instead of using the comments here.